# Преобразовать str в list без изменений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я получаю такую строку `l = ['3:2', '1:1', '2:1']`, как мне из неё сделать список?
Пытался сделать так: `list(l)`, но она разбивает каждый символ:
`['[', "'", '3', ':', '2', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '1', ':', '1', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '2', ':', '1', "'", ']']`

Comment: Укажите точно, как выглядит строка (то, что показано - список), и каков должен быть результат.

Comment: @MBo я так понимаю имелось ввиду `l = "['3:2', '1:1', '2:1']"`, вполне логично, если `list(l)` делит на символы

Comment: @DiMithras Вероятно, но хотелось бы точное ТЗ

Comment: Можно `json.loads(l)` воспользоваться. Только поменять кавычки взаимно с `'` на `"` и `"` на `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
eval(l)
```

Но с eval надо [быть осторожным](https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/), можно неприятные вещи словить.

> Это очень мощная, но в то же время и очень опасная инструкция, особенно если строки, которые вы передаёте в eval, получены не из доверенного источника. Что будет, если строкой, которую мы решим скормить eval'у, окажется os.system('rm -rf /')?

Более безопасной опцией будет `ast` [ответ на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112684/8489602).

```python
import ast

l = "['3:2', '1:1', '2:1']"
ast.literal_eval(l)
```

###### Вывод:

```console
['3:2', '1:1', '2:1']
```

Comment: Не просто быть осторожным, а вообще не использовать eval для парсинга.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

l = "['3:2', '1:1', '2:1']"

answer = re.findall(r"\d+:\d+", l) 
#answer = ['3:2', '1:1', '2:1']

answer1 = [[int(x[0]), int(x[-1])] for x in re.findall(r"\d+:\d+", l)] 
#answer1 = [[3, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1]]
```

Не совсем понял что ты хочешь получить, но из этого думаю без проблем сделаешь как тебе нужно